# IIS7 page redirection with 403 error

Tags: iis-7

First of all, I'm not so close and familiar with IIS7 and using it just for redirection to a weblogic application. 
The backend weblogic application which I use has a login page as a starter page. When I call the page through IIS7, it redirects my requests to weblogic and I see login page. When I try to login with correct pass&user name pair everthing goes fine I can use the system without any problem. However when I try to login with wrong credentials, IIS shows me defaul 403 permission denied page instead of my weblogic applications login error page. 
When I dig the problem a litte bit, I found out that weblogic replys my wrong login attempt with a 403 message which already includes weblogic applications login failed page and when IIS see 403 message, it discards the page in it and just sends me pure 403 response (I've deleted IIS's fancy 403 error message, as well)

Is there any way that iis7 to redirect all requests and responeses without processing it? Changing the reply message code of weblogic application is out of question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

We had an issue where IIS 7 was catching errors responses sent back by weblogic through the ISAPI filter. For example if you put the wrong log in credentials to the log in page. IIS was returning a custom 403 error page and not sending back our apps log in page in weblogic.

This is due to IIS 7 handling custom error codes and sending back its own error pages. See more info at http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors

In order to correct this behavior, we had to set the 
existingResponse='PassThrough' in the httpErrors section of the web.config for the website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I do not use the IIS. It might be enough if you are modifying the paths in the web.config file as follows:

```
<httpErrors>
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/index.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/weblogic/login.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: after your suggestion for web.config,I investigated a bit more and found the page http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors The parameter existingResponse works for me:) Thanks.